# Programmable Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, ios

I would like to know if there exists a bluetooth keyboard which can pair with an iPad on which I can remap keys on the keyboard at a hardware level.

For instance, on my PC and Mac I can force the OS to interpret the Caps Lock key as F10. I use this in many programs.

on the iPad, the Caps Lock key is completely not configurable, even if it is a jailbroken iPad, no software that exists to my knowledge is able to override the OS's treatment of that key. So, the remaining way to get around this is to actually have the keyboard just send the signal of the desired key.

For example: One straightforward but labor intensive method to achieve this goal is to take an existing bluetooth keyboard, non-destructively take it apart, and physically wire up the keys that need to be switched. I could physically cut the traces to the F10 and Caps Lock keys, swap them, and then put the keyboard back together. This way, no programmability or chip reprogramming would be required.

So, if anyone knows of a reasonably compact keyboard that has screws so that it can be nondestructively disassembled, that would be quite helpful as well.